# What is the best way to document websocket messages in Aiohttp/Python?

Tags: python, websocket, swagger, documentation, aiohttp

I use `aiohttp-swagger` to create useful documentation of my http endpoints, but I also have websocket which can send/receive several types of messages (all json for the project), what is the best way to document these messages?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[AsyncAPI](https://www.asyncapi.com/) is the analog of the OpenAPI Specification (fka Swagger Specification) for WebSockets.

As of November 2021 there are the [Asynction](https://pypi.org/project/asynction/) and [Python AsyncAPI](https://pypi.org/project/asyncapi/) projects that let you use AsyncAPI in Python.

You can also write an AsyncAPI definition (YAML or JSON file) for your WebSocket messages manually and display this documentation using one of the [doc renderers](https://www.asyncapi.com/docs/community/tooling#documentation-generators).

Comment: Thanks, I will check how to use it and return to you.